# permission denied, on taskkill

Tags: windows-8, permissions

I have an application that calls `usbpcapcmd.exe`, and runs it. The program runs fine on one machine, but gives permission denied when taskkill is called on another machine. Both computers are Windows8.1, running in administrator mode.

Im not sure what is different. what are some reasons I might see "permission denied", as administrator? I tried setting User Access Control to a minimum setting, but there was no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Given the name `usbpcap`, it is likely that the process has hung on a driver operation or other kernel resource, and is therefore [unkillable](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes/). Make sure the USBPcap driver you are using is the latest one (i.e. not buggy).

The only way to kill this process is by restarting Windows.